# Inserting empty option in the dropdownlist of ListView InsertItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, drop-down-menu

As per title, I have a listview, and in the InsertItemTemplate I have a dropdownlist. I want to add empty option as the first option in the dropdownlist, but it does not seem to be successful.

My code is as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ListAccountType(); // This retrieves the available account types and save into a ViewState
        ...
        BindAccountCode(true);
    }            
}


// This function binds the listview containing the insert item template
private void BindAccountCode(bool QueryDB = false)
{
    // Retrieve the account code and save into a ViewState
    ...

    // Bind the listview
    listviewAccountCode.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState[ACCT];
    listviewAccountCode.DataBind();
    ....
}

protected void listviewAccountCode_ItemCreated(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.InsertItem)
        BindAccountType((DropDownList)listviewAccountCode.InsertItem.FindControl("ddlAccountType"), true); // ddlAccountType is dropdownlist in the InsertItemTemplate that I want to add the empty option.
}

// This will populate the dropdownlist
private void BindAccountType(DropDownList ddl, bool addEmptyRow = false)
{
    ddl.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState[ACCTTYPE]; // this retrieves the account type that we already have after the Page_Load function.
    ...        
    ddl.DataBind(); // bind the data

    if (addEmptyRow) // here I want to add the empty option as the first option in the dropdownlist.
    {
        ListItem li = new ListItem("", "");
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, li);
    }
}
```

When I trace the code, when stepping into `listviewAccountCode.DataBind();`, this will call the `listviewAccountCode_ItemCreated` function, which will add an empty option at the top of the dropdownlist. But after finishing the function and going back to the `listviewAccountCode.DataBind();`, the empty option is gone. I'm not quite sure why this happens.

Any solution?

**[Update]**: If I just remove the checking `if(addEmptyRow)`, then the dropdownlist will contain the empty option. So I am wondering that the `BindAccountType` is somehow called by some other function, and as the default value is false, then it does not add the empty option. But when does this happen?
I check all my codes in this page that it currently pass `true` for the `addEmptyRow`.

**[Update 2014/06/11]**:
The aspx code is as below:

```
<asp:ListView id="listviewAccountCode" runat="server" OnItemCreated="listviewAccountCode_ItemCreated"
    OnItemDataBound="listviewAccountCode_ItemDataBound" OnItemInserting="listviewAccountCode_ItemInserting"  
    OnItemEditing="listviewAccountCode_ItemEditing" OnItemUpdating="listviewAccountCode_ItemUpdating"
    OnItemCanceling="listviewAccountCode_ItemCanceling"
    InsertItemPosition="LastItem" OnPagePropertiesChanging="listviewAccountCode_PagePropertiesChanging"                    
    >
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                // List of columns
                ...
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            // List of columns
            ..
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            // List of columns
            ..
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAccountType" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            ..
        </tr>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            // List of columns
            ..
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAccountType" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            ..
        </tr>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                // List of columns
                ..
            </tr>
            <tr style="height:20px"><td colspan="14"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>                    
</asp:ListView>
<asp:DataPager ID="datapagerResult" runat="server" PagedControlID="listviewAccountCode" OnPreRender="datapagerResult_PreRender">
    <Fields>
        <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="10"/>
    </Fields>
</asp:DataPager>
```

**Update[2014/06/11-2]**:
In this case, I have 4 items, so it will be 5 items with the empty option at the top.
Upon calling `BindAccountCode(true);`, it goes into `listviewAccountCode.DataBind();` then it will call `listviewAccountCode_ItemCreated` event and `BindAccountType((DropDownList)listviewAccountCode.InsertItem.FindControl("ddlAccountType"), true);` which sets the number of items to be 5. But when returning to `listviewAccountCode.DataBind();`, it magically becomes 9 items. Don't know what's happening there.

Answer (score 0):

in your `BindAccountType` method add the empty item into your dropdownlist first and use AppendDataBoundItems property then do the data binding like this:

> ```
>   private void BindAccountType(DropDownList ddl, bool addEmptyRow = false)
>     {
>         ddl.Items.Clear(); //try this before you bind your list
>         if (addEmptyRow) 
>         {
>             ListItem li = new ListItem("", "");
>             ddl.Items.Insert(0, li);
>             ddl.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
>         }
>         ddl.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState[ACCTTYPE]; // this retrieves the account type that we already have after the Page_Load function.
>         ...        
>         ddl.DataBind(); // bind the data
>     }
> ```

**UPDATE 1**
I just tested this one it's working Ok.

```
    private void BindAccountType(DropDownList ddl, bool addEmptyRow = false)
    {
        ddl.Items.Clear();
        ddl.AppendDataBoundItems = addEmptyRow;

        if (addEmptyRow) 
           DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("", ""));

        ddl.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState[ACCTTYPE]; 
        ddl.DataValueField = "your table value";
        ddl.DataTextField = "your table text";
        ddl.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: There is still some issue. When I use the code you provided, the dropdownlist in the `InsertItemTemplate` contains twice amount of the items being inserted, minus 1. So for example if the item is `A,B` and we will insert an empty option at the top, then it will have 5 items ` ,A,A,B,B`. So somehow it's like this function is called twice, and the second calling sets the `addEmptyRow` to false. I think the major culprit is why is this function called twice.

Your particular code can add the empty row, just that it is still called twice.

Comment: just add one more line to the code, try that one and let me know about the result

Comment: sorry, no difference whether I clear the dropdownlist first or not.

Comment: if you can put your aspx code for me, then I might be able to help you with that. just the code that you are using it for this bit below would be enough:`(DropDownList)listviewAccountCode.InsertItem.FindControl("ddlAccountType")`

Comment: just added an update + it's better to change ID of one of your drop down control like:  `ID="ddlAccountType"` to  `ID="ddlAccountType2"` so it's not the same as each others.

Comment: if those id are auto generated by the list view then leave them as they are.

Comment: Strange, I still get the same thing, despite renaming the ddlAccountType differently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55411/discussion-between-ali-shahrokhi-and-rcs).

Comment: check your data-source values using break point to see if they are duplicated.  ==>> `(DataTable)ViewState[ACCTTYPE];`

Comment: The datasource values are correct. It contains 4 items.